# how can I add elements of an array to the URL with react-router-dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

how can I add elements of an array to the URL with react-router-dom v6?

example

const params = [iphone,samsung,honor]

/products/query=iphone,samsung,honor

Answer (score 0):

you can pass anything to the URL by using useHistory Hook, here is the example:

```
const history = useHistory()
    history.push({
          pathname: "/my-profile/my-reservations",
          search: "?" + new URLSearchParams({ activeTab: "xyz" }).toString(),
        });
```

Comment: FYI, `useHistory` is ***not*** a `react-router-dom@6` hook.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `Array.toString()` to turn your array into a string and then a [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to format your url:

```
params = [iphone,samsung,honor];
const paramString = params.toString();
const urlFormatted = `/products/query=${paramString}`;
console.log(urlFormatted);
```